# How do I set the default boot back to Ubuntu on a Macbook after setting it to macOS?

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro

I wanted to setup Ubuntu on my son's laptop, to introduce him to linux. but I wanted the default OS to be Mac so he won't have trouble just jumping in to a new OS. He's just 10 years old .

I managed to make it default boot into Mac os by choosing it on the startup disk. So when he wants to try Ubuntu, he just presses option on startup.

But now I was wondering  how to default boot back to Ubuntu. The efi disk doesn't appear on the startup disks.

The machine is an old macbook pro 2012. Os is Catalina and Ubuntu latest version LTS

Thanks

Comment: After pressing option on startup, hold down the control key while selecting Ubuntu.